# Why nova threadgroup cannot access database (nova-network)? "Can't connect to MySQL server"

Tags: networking, nova

I've just build the basic version of the openstack and everything works but network. I've installed nova-network but I'm not sure if it's correctly installed.

I've installed it on the compute node, because all other machines are virtualized. So I want it to deal with physical interfaces.

The problem is that it fails to handle network:

2013-11-24 22:42:03.770 3570 ERROR nova.openstack.common.threadgroup [-] (OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'controller.cloud.level2crm.com' (113)") None None

This happens no matter what I set on configuration.

Why?

**[Update]** It turns out that I was hit by this in my saucy installation, I'm getting crazy with this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu-kvm/+bug/997978

Comment: I've discovered that neutron has same problem, so maybe I'm doing something wrong, but what? 2013-11-25 10:32:18.225 2534 CRITICAL neutron [-] (OperationalError) (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'controller.cloud.level2crm.com' (2)") None None
n

Answer (score 0):

By default, mysql only accepts connections from the local host.

Look in your /etc/mysql/my.cnf (on the controller node) for the following line and comment it out or change to allow connections in your applicable subnet.

```
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
```

changes to (or you can remove it)

```
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

Then restart mysql server

```
user@openstack-ctlr:~$ sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: Yes, I know, that was not the problem. I added this on install and also added permissions to all hosts on the net for every openstack user.